# How do you determine which Dominion sets to play with?

Tags: dominion

I'm well aware of the randomizers available for Dominion, but how do you determine which sets to include in a randomizer?

For example, I own Base, Intrigue, Seaside, Prosperity & Dark Ages. Lately, I've been using a randomizer between all the sets but I feel like I'm losing out on the built in interactions. How do you do it? Do you choose a handful of sets? If so, how do you determine which ones and how many?

Thanks

Comment: http://i.qkme.me/3scttn.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no general way to pick the sets besides picking ones that you like.

I generally restrict myself to 2-4 sets of cards because I like to play with at least 2-3 cards from each set I am playing with (this is especially true if playing with alchemy).

In my opinion, the only 2 sets that I have found to clash, and its not even that bad when they do, are dark ages and hinterlands.

You might also consider reading this question: [Does mixing Dominion expansions lessen the power of card combinations in random kingdom setups?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/does-mixing-dominion-expansions-lessen-the-power-of-card-combinations-in-random)

Comment: Which sets are your favorites to combine?

Answer (score 6):

One interesting houserule we have successfully experimented with is this:

> The first four cards are chosen randomly from all your randomizers. After that, every further randomizer is discarded unless it matches a set from one of the first four, until you have ten cards total.

This method usually gives cards from 3 sets; sometimes 4 and rarely 2 (and very rarely 1, but I've never seen it!). You could of course tweak the number to your taste.